# How to code better this multiple select subquery(subqueries)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically below query now works in order to retrieve what I want.

But I'm pretty sure there is a more efficient way to write this query:

```
SELECT dg.ultimo_codigo_de_gestion_prejuridico, dg.hora_inicio_gestion, 
       dg.telefono, dg.fecha_gestion, cg.valor_codigo, cg.contacto 
FROM detalle_gestion_con_obligacion 
AS dg INNER JOIN codigo_gestion 
AS cg ON dg.ultimo_codigo_de_gestion_prejuridico = cg.cod_gestion  
WHERE nro_documento = 1234567 
  AND DATE(fecha_gestion) NOT IN (2018-10-20) AND telefono 
  IN ((SELECT tel_residencia FROM obligacion WHERE nro_obligacion = 1234567) ,
      (SELECT tel_oficina FROM obligacion WHERE nro_obligacion = 1234567), 
      (SELECT celular FROM obligacion WHERE nro_obligacion = 1234567), 
      (SELECT tel_residencia1 FROM obligacion WHERE nro_obligacion = 1234567) ) 
ORDER BY fecha_gestion DESC, hora_inicio_gestion DESC limit 1;
```

As you might tell, around the `IN` clause I want to retrieve agreements `(detalle_gestion_con_obligacion)` where the telephone belongs to that list.

I am looking for a better solution that doesn't need four different `SELECT` statements.

Answer (score 2):

You can join with `obligacion` instead of using `IN`.

```
SELECT dg.ultimo_codigo_de_gestion_prejuridico, dg.hora_inicio_gestion, 
       dg.telefono, dg.fecha_gestion, cg.valor_codigo, cg.contacto 
FROM detalle_gestion_con_obligacion AS dg 
INNER JOIN codigo_gestion AS cg ON dg.ultimo_codigo_de_gestion_prejuridico = cg.cod_gestion  
INNER JOIN obligacion AS o ON telefono IN (o.tel_residencia, o.yel_oficina, o.celular, o.tel_residencial)
WHERE nro_documento = 1234567 
  AND DATE(fecha_gestion) NOT IN (2018-10-20) 
ORDER BY fecha_gestion DESC, hora_inicio_gestion DESC 
limit 1;
```

Comment: Totally missed that they were all in the same table. Saw different column names and mistook those for the table names. Your answer is better.